# Coding for Ethernet PHY Loopback Test

Tags: linux, ethernet, loopback

I have to write a Ethernet PHY loopback test in Linux. I've never done it before and had no clue where to start. After some researching, I came up with the plan for the test, and I wonder if anyone can help me to verify it and give me some pointers to my questions.

This is a external loopback setup. It connects the TX+/- to RX+/- pins for each internal PHY's on the Ethernet switch chip.

So the loopback high level packet path is as follow:

CPU->PHY0(chip)->Ethernet switch(chip)'s internal PHY->PHY0(chip)->CPU

For this test, I plan to

1. configure the internal PHYs on the Ethernet switch with specific MAC addresses,
2. pack the Ethernet test packet using CPU's MAC address as the source address and the
   MAC address configured in step 1. as the destination address,
3. send and wait to receive the test packet,
4. compare sent and received data pattern.

Any suggestions? Also, I wonder if there are functions in Linux that I can use to generate the packets for step 2, and send the packets for step 3.

Thank you very much.

Comment: which language do you want to use for this test?

Comment: Hi, Did you eventually did the loopback test on linux or in bootloader ? Thanks

Comment: Wow, my rely is so late. Yes, I make it working in bootloader. Tim's answer came too late, but I found a similar approach elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Most Phys can be switched to a test mode. We used the bootloader to write directly to the
Phy and switch to testing mode.

There is also an ioctl taken from documentation/networking/phy.txt
   Ethtool convenience functions.

int phy_mii_ioctl(struct phy_device *phydev,
                 struct mii_ioctl_data *mii_data, int cmd);

The MII ioctl.  Note that this function will completely screw up the state
   machine if you write registers like BMCR, BMSR, ADVERTISE, etc.  Best to
   use this only to write registers which are not standard, and don't set off
   a renegotiation.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I didn't see your answer until now. Yes, your answer should work for internal loopback test. However, for the external loopback test (with external loopback connector), we don't need to put the PHY into test mode. Just set it to full duplex mode and auto-negotiation, and use the bootloader phy_mii API to send and receive the data.